# python 3.10.10 - No module named 'azure'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, python-3.10

I am trying to deploy my sample application to azure app service in linux.
my application is a simple flask application that get's a key from the user and retrieves it's value from azure key vault.

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
```

my requirements.txt is as follows:

```
azure-mgmt-resource
Flask==2.0.2
azure-identity==1.10.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.6.0
```

I have tried adding only azure but it throws me the following error and now I have no idea how to exit this loop:

```
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-x2lo6n9j/azure_e4ab6d93138d4411b0a31c7f2ffe6ad2/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError(message)
      RuntimeError:
      
      Starting with v5.0.0, the 'azure' meta-package is deprecated and cannot be installed anymore.
      Please install the service specific packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application.
      
      The complete list of available packages can be found at:
      https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/all
      
      Here's a non-exhaustive list of common packages:
      
      -  azure-mgmt-compute (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-compute) : Management of Virtual Machines, etc.
      -  azure-mgmt-storage (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-storage) : Management of storage accounts.
      -  azure-mgmt-resource (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-resource) : Generic package about Azure Resource Management (ARM)
      -  azure-keyvault-secrets (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-keyvault-secrets) : Access to secrets in Key Vault
      -  azure-storage-blob (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-storage-blob) : Access to blobs in storage accounts
      
      A more comprehensive discussion of the rationale for this decision can be found in the following issue:
      https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10646
      
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

The pip install code I use in my azure pipeline is as follows:

```
  - script: |
      python -m venv env
      source env/bin/activate
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
```

Answer (score 0):

***Cause of the error:*** `Azure` meta-package cannot be installed in the current application. Instead, install the specific provider packages that your application requires.

*Install the required packages with the latest versions in the* `visual studio code` *terminal using below* `pip` *commands.*

```bash
pip install azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
pip install azure-identity
pip install azure-mgmt-resource
pip install Flask
```

*Once it is updated all the required packages, use below* `pip` *command to update the* `requirements.txt` *file.*

```py
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can find all the Azure SDK's here in [Azure SDK releases](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html).

***Installed & updated successfully:***

[image]

*To check whether the flask is running fine, I created a sample application, and it ran successfully as shown:*

[image]

Refer [key vault secret client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python?tabs=azure-cli) for more relevant information as per your requirement.

Comment: Hello @Jahnavi and thank you for your answer, I am not working with vs code and the issue happens after deployment (I have edited the question and added the pipeline part - I am using the same sample app that you shared but instead of inserting my name, I insert the key i want to retrieve the value from key vault (have a try) - locally it worked for me but after deploy not

Comment: Make sure that you are running `pip install -r requirements.txt` before running the script of the pipeline itself and add the required packages with the pip command in your pipeline script as I detailed in the above answer. @Elim

Comment: If still the issue persists, try deleting a virtual environment and create a new virtual environment of python and run the script. @Elim